# Unclear error message when adding ResourceDirectory

Tags: wpf

I have added the asection from a sample I found into the Application resources.

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna, Version=3.0.0.0,
                            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
                            ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/luna.metallic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

That indeed changes the Theme to Luna. However, although the program works it marks the Source as in error and the underlines it with a blue waveline.

[image]

Comment: Can you change the relative uri for a (pack uri)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf]? something like this: pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.1;component/ResourceFile.xaml

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps :-

1. Select the line `<ResourceDictionary Source=""/>`
2. Press F4 button or whichever shortcut is configured for Properties Window.
3. In the Source option, you will see the available resources in your project. It will automatically detect the type to be referred and also insert the pack or relative URL whichever is needed, based on BuildAction.

Hope that helps.

[image: Try this]

Comment: But it it does not show up in the resources, you might need to use the PackURI to get it resolved.

Comment: It is resolved correctly, I think. The program successfully turns to the luna theme. But Visual Studio shows an error nevertheless.